# GCP's CloudSQL - Recreate existing read replica

Tags: google-cloud-sql, database-replication

We require to execute some SQL scripts that causes our replication delay (on our read-replica) to sky rocket.

Replication delay will resolve itself only after ~24 hours or so.

It is of course faster for us to create a new replica instead of replicating the data.

We don't want to create a new read replica as we have many clients that are already using the existing replica.

The question is: **"How can we force the existing read-replica to be recreated?"** (maintaining its static address and configuration as is)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the documentation covers, it does not seem possible to automatically reset or rebuild a read-replica. The documentation covers only manually recreating a read-replica by deleting and creating a new one. However, there are recommendations to avoid creating replication delay, the primary one being [parallel replication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/manage-replicas#configuring-parallel-replication). Parallel replication helps you by creating multiple threads to handle replication:

> Parallel replication reduces replication lag by increasing the number of SQL threads that work to execute these transactions. Read replicas with parallel replication enabled are sometimes called multithreaded replicas.

You can also attempt to optimize your SQL scripts to avoid creating intense delay while using parallel replication among [other tips](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica#troubleshooting). Otherwise, there are REST API endpoints that can help you to [delete](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1/instances/delete) and [create](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica#rest-v1) new replicas so that the manual recreation process becomes smoother. Particularly, the create replica endpoint allows you to pass multiple configuration options relevant to the machine tier, region, name, the replication fields among others.